# Rasterize Geometry Example not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasterizing, rasterio

I am trying to recreate [this rasterio example](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/examples/rasterize_geometry.py):

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.features import rasterize
from rasterio.transform import IDENTITY

rows = cols = 10

geometry = {
    'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[(2, 2), (2, 4.25), (4.25, 4.25), (4.25, 2), (2, 2)]]
}


with rasterio.Env():
    result = rasterize([geometry], out_shape=(rows, cols))
    with rasterio.open(
            "test.tif",
            'w',
            driver='GTiff',
            width=cols,
            height=rows,
            count=1,
            dtype=np.uint8,
            nodata=0,
            transform=IDENTITY,
            crs={'init': "EPSG:4326"}) as out:
        out.write(result.astype(np.uint8), indexes=1)
```

I have checked the result of `rasterize` (`print(result)`) which seems normal and sould result in a 2x2 pixel square:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

But I am getting a completely black image (`nodata` image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I cannot define the reason for the black `.tif` image, I concluded that the process works as intended and we can see a visual result using `matplolib.pyplot`.

The example must be modified as follows to use `pyplot`:

```
import rasterio
from matplotlib import pyplot
from rasterio.features import rasterize
from rasterio.transform import IDENTITY

rows = cols = 10

geometry = {
    'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[(2, 2), (2, 4.25), (4.25, 4.25), (4.25, 2), (2, 2)]]
}


with rasterio.Env():
    result = rasterize([geometry], out_shape=(rows, cols))
    with rasterio.open(
            "test.tif",
            'w+', # Open the file in read/write mode
            driver='GTiff',
            width=cols,
            height=rows,
            count=1,
            dtype=rasterio.uint8,
            nodata=0,
            transform=IDENTITY,
            crs={'init': "EPSG:4326"}) as out:
        out.write(result.astype(rasterio.uint8), indexes=1)
        # Plot the image.
        pyplot.imshow(out.read(1))
        pyplot.show()
```